# Regular Expression - Match substring that doesn't contain specified string literal

Tags: regex

With the regular expression `\*\*([^\*]*)\*\*` I can match multiple groups of text inside `**`'s such as:

`this **is** a **test**`

Returning `is` & `test`.

Given the string `that's **right * a test**`, how do I adjust my expression to return `right * a test`? How do I get my expression to exclude two `*`'s instead of just one?

http://regex101.com/r/aD3pC2

Comment: What language is this for? Regexes differ between languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the reluctant quantifier `.*?`:

```
\*\*.*?\*\*
```

assuming it is supported by your regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `or`:

```
\*\*((?:[^*]|\*[^*])*)\*\*
```

Inside the matching group, this will match any character that is not a star, or a star followed by a non-star. The *first* occurrence of a double-star (`**`) is assumed to signal the end of string literal. If the string content is meant to end with a star (like `**my string ends with a star***`), my regex won't include the final star in the match (so the string content will simply be "`my string ends with a star`"). But I think that's valid as just described.

However if the string literal starts with a star like `***Star Power!**`, it will include the star in the string content, which I think is also valid because the first occurrence of `**` marks the start of the string literal, and the following single `*` is just part of the content.

Also, note that you don't need to escape stars inside the character class (in most implementations).

Comment: It will, however, match a single star at the start of a string literal, `***such as this one**`

Comment: "Ending star doesn't work (probably shouldn't) ... Beginning star works (probably should)" ... wat?

Comment: If the string content is meant to end with a star (like `**my string ends with***`), my regex won't include the final star in the match, but I think that's valid because the first occurrence of `**` terminates the string literal. However if the string literal starts with a star like the one you pointed out, it will include the star in the string content, which I think is also valid because the first occurence of `**` marks the start of the string literal, and the following single `*` is just part of the content.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm That was a really good explanation, and you may want to edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all the nasty escaping I will just use this regex:

```
([*][*])(.*?)\1
```

And grab matched group #2.

**Live Demo:** http://www.rubular.com/r/hJY1eXnLty

Comment: I really like using the square brackets instead of escaping. It definitely makes it easier for my eyes to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern:

```
 \*\*((?:[^*]|[^*]\*[^*])*)\*\*
```

It will match any pair of `*` characters, followed by zero or more of any character other than `*` or a `*` surrounded by characters other than `*`, followed by another pair of `*` characters.

Comment: Doesn't match correctly if the string literal starts with a star, ***like this.**

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm true, but that wasn't specified as a requirement. It's entirely possible OP wants `***test**` to match just `test` rather than `*test`.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't explicitly mentioned. But assuming left to right parsing, the first occurrence of `**` marks the beginning of the string and all subsequent content until the next occurrence of `**` is part of the string. Like in C, `///A comment` is treated as `<comment>/A comment</comment>`, as opposed to `<slash /><comment>A comment</comment>`.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm I thought OP was trying to parse something like markdown, as in your example `***like this**` is parsed as ***like this**.

Comment: That's right, markdown works the same way: notice that the `*` is part of the bolded content. With your expression, the star would preceded the bolded content: http://regex101.com/r/fG0iF6

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the reluctant quantifier you can use this:

```
\*\*((?:[^*]|[*](?=[^*]))+)\*\*
```

Explanation: this will match any character other than '*' or '*' that is not followed by a '*' between the pair of '**'